# How do I submit a form with javascript when there's an input named submit?

Tags: javascript

Normally `form.submit()` will work,

but if there's an input named `submit`,

`form.submit` will be the very input and you can't submit the form with the above code.

So is there a way to submit the form in this case(if I don't change the input's name)?

Answer (score 5):

You can invoke the submit method from another form and hack `this` with `call` or `apply`.

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call(myForm);
```

… but it won't work on IE6.

It is safer to rename the input to something other than submit.

Comment: @new_perl — No, which is why jQuery's `submit()` method doesn't try to recover from the input name / default method name conflict.

Comment: @kirilloid — Yes, the method is the method. It doesn't go away if the form is in the DOM.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I know. I meant: "Will it work in IE6?". Also I have an idea with double-trick. Rename input named `submit`, get form's own method, rename input back and call the method the same way. Or is there intrinsic limitation in IE6 on calling DOM element methods with `call`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "submit" is a reserved word and can't be used in any input element except the `type=submit` element.

But there is always a way to break the rules.
By using AJAX to perform a POST request, you can use any name you want.
And you don't even need a name for the input element, just an id.
As a matter of fact, you don't even need a form, just an input element.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxRequest()
{
 var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]
 if(window.ActiveXObject)
 {
  for(var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++)
  {
   try{return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])}
   catch(e){}
   }
  }
 else if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
 else
  return false
 }

function myfunc()
{
 var mypostrequest=new ajaxRequest()
 mypostrequest.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if(mypostrequest.readyState==4)
  {
   if(mypostrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)
   {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mypostrequest.responseText
    }
   }
  }
 var hiddenValue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("submit").value)
 var parameters="submit="+hiddenValue
 mypostrequest.open("POST", "go2.php", true)
 mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 mypostrequest.send(parameters)
 }
window.onload = myfunc;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<input type='hidden' id='submit' value='1'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the .click() function on the submit button. If there is no submit button you would have to insert one into the DOM first though.

Like this:

```
var submitbutton = document.createElement('input');
submitbutton.type = "submit";
document.getElementById("yourForm").appendChild(submitbutton);
submitbutton.click();
```

Or, if you have a submit button:

```
document.getElementById("yourButton").click()
```